# Hello I think I got scam and need validation of it

Tags: scam, bot, trading

Hello can someone validate the contract I've created was indeed a scam. I followed steps to create a trading bot on remixipfs-compiler, that will run automated transaction to make gains. but the money I've sent in to the contract never reached the balance when I look at it. like the money went elsewhere ,

this is the transaction hash: 0xbed38cb79547c562795d9ad85cd900a2af87b9011f1e130a2ec8d5541b9e127b

Comment: code of the contract : https://codepastes.com/raw/HKKxGO

Comment: yes it's a scam